# Gallery not getting button click

Tags: android

In ma application I am using a gallery widget having an ImageView and a button. I am able to get the Imageview click on gallery.setOnItemClickListener event, but I am not getting ma button click . how can I get the button click. Please help me.

Please look into ma code:

```
public ImageAdapter(Activity c,Integer[] images) {
        this.mContext = c;
        this.Images=images;
        TypedArray attr = mContext.obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.HelloGal999lery);
        mGalleryItemBackground = attr.getResourceId(
                R.styleable.HelloGal999lery_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
        attr.recycle();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return Images.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 1;
    }

    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent __e) {
        return false;
    }


     static class ViewHolder{
        public ImageView imageView1;
        public ImageButton btn1;
     }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  

         ViewHolder holder; 
         View rowView = convertView;

        if(rowView==null)
        {
         LayoutInflater inflater = mContext.getLayoutInflater();
         rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test, null, true);
         holder=new ViewHolder();
         holder.imageView1=(ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ImageViewuser);    
         holder.btn1=(ImageButton)rowView.findViewById(R.id.Download);
         holder.imageView1.setImageResource(Images[position]);               
         holder.imageView1.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
         holder.imageView1.setBackgroundResource(mGalleryItemBackground);                
        }
        // rowView.setMinimumHeight(100);
         return rowView;                    
    }
```

**Ma parent layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"    
     >  


            <Gallery  
        android:id="@+id/gallery"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:spacing="10dp"            
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

**Ma child layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   <ImageView 
       android:id="@+id/ImageViewuser"
       android:layout_width="150dip"
       android:layout_height="150dip"         

       />
<ImageButton 
    android:id="@+id/Download"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ImageViewuser"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"    
    android:background="@drawable/clearall1"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you did't wrote code for click events, add onClick() function for button in the `getView()` method

```
holder.btn1=(ImageButton)rowView.findViewById(R.id.Download);     
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
     ///  write code here  
   }     
});
```

you can get position here

and also
you can get position like this 
position of the item in gallery

```
gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
      Toast.makeText(GalleryActivity.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
});
```

Comment: I want to get aslo the position of the selected gallery picture.How can i get this

Comment: we can get that position of the item by gallery.setOnItemClickListener() check my answer now

Comment: Thanks for giving me the solution. This code helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

set the `onclickListener` on your `ImageButton` on the `getView()` method , and then you have the position of the `ImageButton` clicked :

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
     ///  your code 
   }     
});
```

**NB :** About the position , you already have it on the params of the `getView()` method , you can use it inside the `onClick()` method

Comment: No..this is not ma main class